# How do I change the font color of mode-line?

Tags: faces, mode-line, colors

How do I change the font color of the mode-line to make it more visible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call the bottom bar is the "mode line".  I recommend reading the first fews sections of the manual, especially [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Screen.html#Screen) to know the names of the various screen elements (this is not difficult at all, but not straightforward for newcomers.) The graphical attributes of text in emacs are grouped in "faces". As mentionned in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Optional-Mode-Line.html#Optional-Mode-Line):

> By default, the mode line of nonselected windows is displayed in a different face, called mode-line-inactive. Only the selected window is displayed in the mode-line face. This helps show which window is selected.

So the answer is to customize the face `mode-line`.  To do so, you can look at the face definition by typing `M-x describe-face RET mode-line RET` and from that select the "customize this font" link (or you can directly use `M-x customize-face`).  Customization is rather straightforward, but if you want to know more, see the manual section on [customizing faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html#Face-Customization).

Comment: If the name of the face is known, a user can type `M-x customize-face` ....  Depending upon how many faces are present at the given location and depending upon the version of Emacs, the desired face may even be the default first choice when typing the aforementioned function ...

Comment: @lawlist Didn't know about this smart default choice, very nice!

Comment: Heads up, Emacs 29.1 added the face `mode-line-active` in a way that broke certain customizations of the `mode-line` face, which is now just for things that are common to both active and inactive mode lines. For example, if you were doing something like `(face-remap-add-relative 'mode-line :background ...)` to change the mode line color per-buffer, you now have to do `(face-remap-add-relative 'mode-line-active :background ...)`.